# Goodix Touchscreen Driver Stylus shares id with touchscreen

Tags: linux-kernel, x11, drivers, touch-screen

I am trying to get the touchscreen working with active stylus support on a One Netbook 1s. The problem is that the stylus is detected like a click. It shares the same id as the touchscreen so when it is in the vicinity of the screen it acts like a continuous click.

The output of `xinput-list` is:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HAILUCK CO.,LTD USB KEYBOARD Mouse        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver Mouse                 id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver Consumer Control      id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen             id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HAILUCK CO.,LTD USB KEYBOARD              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HAILUCK CO.,LTD USB KEYBOARD System Control   id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HAILUCK CO.,LTD USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control id=13   [slave  keyboard
```

This problem seems to have been fixed with this modified driver: https://gitlab.com/AdyaAdya/goodix-touchscreen-linux-driver

However after following the instructions in the readme of that link, the driver makes the stylus stop working altogether, although the touchscreen still works.

The output of `dmesg | grep -i goodix` before loading the modified driver is:

```
[    4.771020] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1001:00: i2c-GDIX1001:00 supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.771041] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1001:00: i2c-GDIX1001:00 supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.772795] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1001:00: ID 9111, version: 4020
[    4.790648] input: Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/i2c_designware.2/i2c-3/i2c-GDIX1001:00/input/input16
```

while after running

```
# rmmod goodix
# insmod goodix.ko
```

as the instructions say, `dmesg | grep -i goodix` gives us:

```
[    4.771020] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1001:00: i2c-GDIX1001:00 supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.771041] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1001:00: i2c-GDIX1001:00 supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.772795] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1001:00: ID 9111, version: 4020
[    4.790648] input: Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/i2c_designware.2/i2c-3/i2c-GDIX1001:00/input/input16
[  711.634820] goodix: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  711.634976] goodix: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  711.638265] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1001:00: i2c-GDIX1001:00 supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[  711.638303] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1001:00: i2c-GDIX1001:00 supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[  711.641037] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1001:00: ID 9111, version: 4020
[  711.647527] input: Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/i2c_designware.2/i2c-3/i2c-GDIX1001:00/input/input25
[  711.657476] input: Goodix Active Stylus Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/i2c_designware.2/i2c-3/i2c-GDIX1001:00/input/input26
```

As you can see it now mentions an "active stulus pen" in the last line but the stylus is not working. The touchscreen still works. The stylus still does not show up on `xinput list`

I would not be surprised if I am misunderstanding how to apply these directions. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of these outputs, I suspect the problem comes from missing resolution information for the stylus that is required for `libinput` to recognize it as a "Tablet device".

To learn more about what I mean, please refer to the [Troubleshooting section](https://gitlab.com/AdyaAdya/goodix-touchscreen-linux-driver#resolution-information-missing-for-libinput) dedicated to that issue.

In a nutshell, if you do have this issue, you need to provide the resolution information to `udev` as described in the link above.

(I also replied [on the repository issue you posted](https://gitlab.com/AdyaAdya/goodix-touchscreen-linux-driver/issues/7#note_280733768))

Comment: Actually yeah that was it. Turns out I had some other things messed up which made those steps not so easy to follow... 

Sorry for not replying earlier!